# Can I retrieve hard drive diagnostics on a Linux System?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I am running Linux-2.4 system, and I am attempting to retrieve hard drive diagnostics information, any that might be available.  Is there a way that I can retrieve these hard drive statistics?

Comment: http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/55366

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into "smartmontools". This package contains two utility programs that can provide advanced warning of disk degradation and failure.

Comment: Also note it's free/opensource. (A lot of times I think 1 rep users are spammers, so.. )

Answer (score 1):

Two tools that will help you are hdparm and smartmontools.

**hdparm**: It will depend on your distribution of Linux, but almost every distribution I have used will have it already installed.  Use the command `hdparm -I [device node name]` like `hdparm -I /dev/sda`

**smartmontools**: You will probably have to install this one yourself. Use your package manager or download [this](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/Download) will give you the information you need to install.  Once installed, you will want to check the man page, but if you want to just dive into your diagnostics, you can type something like `smartctl --all /dev/sda` (or whatever your device node name is).